# How to send the contents of a text area to a function in Typescript / Javascript / Html

Tags: javascript, html, function, typescript, devextreme

Probably a very simple question, but I can't seem to find a way of sending a piece of data from a textarea to a javascript/typescript function.

**HTML**

```
  <div  data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } " >
        <p> use this page to log errors</p>
        <p id="prevErrors" style="font-style:italic">PreviousErrors</p>
        <br />
        <div id="curError" data-bind="dxTextArea: { }"></div>
        <br />
        <div  data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Save and return to main menu' }" onclick="    saveMyData(document.getElementById(curError).innerText)"></div>
    </div>
```

**Java/TypeScript**

```
<script>


        function saveMyData(curError) {
            //this will be where data is saved or emailed
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            var h = today.getHours(); 
            var m = today.getMinutes(); 
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            if (dd < 10) {
                dd = '0' + dd
            }
            if (h < 10) {
                h = "0" + h;
            }
            if (s < 10)
            {
                s = "0"+s;
            }
            if (m < 10) {
                m = "0"+m;
            }
            if (mm < 10) {
                mm = '0' + mm
            }

            today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy +" , "+h+":"+m+":"+s;
            prevErrors.innerText +=  "\n "+today+", "+curError;
        }
    </script>
```

Having only recently found out that typescript and javascript are virtually identical anyway, I feel slightly embarrassed that starting up typescript has been such a battle - nothing like c#/vb/etc.

**QUESTION**

I have been trying to send data from this `dxtextArea` control to a function. as you can see, I have already tried using the *innerText*, however, this seems to send nothing into the function (getting the error:

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null', line 1, file 'http://localhost:51828/index.html#'.
```

even when data is present in the textArea.

Anyone come across this issue/know how to solve it/ or is it just my stupidity and naivety in knowledge of Java/typescript?

**EDIT**

I have been told to change my Method call from innerText to value (and add quotes around the ID), but this still hasn't solved the issue:

```
saveMyData(document.getElementById('curError').value)"
```

**EDIT 2** My Full Script:

```
<div data-options="dxView : { name: 'ErrorLogging', title: 'ErrorLogging' } " >
    <div  data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } " >
        <p>Use this page to log errors</p>
        <br />
        <p style="font-style:italic">PreviousErrors</p>
        <p id="prevErrors" style="font-style:italic"></p>
        <br />
        <div id="curError" data-bind="dxTextArea: { }" ></div>
        <br />
        <div  data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Save and return to main menu' }" onclick="saveMyData(document.getElementById('curError').textContent)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

    function saveMyData(elem) {
        //this will be where data is saved or emailed


        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        var h = today.getHours(); 
        var m = today.getMinutes(); 
        var s = today.getSeconds();

        //add a '0' in front of single digit values
        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd
        }
        if (h < 10) {
            h = "0" + h;
        }
        if (s < 10)
        {
            s = "0"+s;
        }
        if (m < 10) {
            m = "0"+m;
        }
        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = '0' + mm
        }

        if (elem.textContent) {
            var curError = elem.textContent ?
                elem.textContent :
                elem.innerText;
        }
        alert(curError);

        today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy +" , "+h+":"+m+":"+s; //created string containing todays' date and time
        prevErrors.innerText += "\n " + today + ", " + elem;

    }
</script>
```

[image: Image of what it will look like on ios]

Comment: is prevErrors declared? use document.getElementById("prevErrors").innerText

Comment: @DennisAnderson prevErrors is working fine (adding the date/time, just not the contents of the TextArea)

Comment: is your script added after the html content?

Comment: @YassineMoustarham, yes- i'm pretty sure that's normal practise is it not?

Comment: @MrCoder just in case !

Comment: @MrCoder you should maybe access prevErrors with document.getElementById('prevErrors').innerText

Comment: @YassineMoustarham I can't see how that's gonna sort out the **curError**, as I am able to write/update **prevErrors** - just (currently)- that's not my issue! :(

Comment: so is it declared somewhere else ?if not you should realy check it
because the error comes from the variable where you call the innerText property which means prevErrors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61364/discussion-between-mrcoder-and-yassine-moustarham).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that by using

`var val = $("#textArea").dxTextArea("instance").option("value");`

Allowed me to get the ID called `textArea`, which could then be used without the method/function call.

So now, I could use the code:

```
prevErrors.innerText += "\n " + today + ", " + val;
```

to be able to get the dxTextArea's input into the data.

Problem solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to check.

Number 1 - you have to ensure that the function `saveMyData` is declared before it is used. You will know if you haven't done this as you'll get an error such as:

> ReferenceError: saveMyData is not defined

Number 2 - `innerText` is notoriously tricky, but the standard `textContent` is usually a better bet in modern browsers.

```
document.getElementById('curError').textContent
```

Note - `textContent` is IE9 and above (and pretty much all other browsers). To get below IE9 support, you'll need to test the feature!

If you passed the element, you could do the test inside the function, here is a working version that you can run:

```js
function saveMyData(elem) {
    if (elem.textContent) {
        var curError = elem.textContent ? 
            elem.textContent : 
            elem.innerText;
    }
    alert(curError);
}
```

```html
 <div  data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } " >
        <p> use this page to log errors</p>
        <p id="prevErrors" style="font-style:italic">PreviousErrors</p>
        <br />
        <div id="curError" data-bind="dxTextArea: { }">Test Text</div>
        <br />
        <div  data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Save and return to main menu' }" onclick="saveMyData(document.getElementById('curError'));">Click Me</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help/advice, I tried your code snippet- and yes, it works (sort of). but when i run the program, that 'Test Text' isn't actually within the dxTextArea (it shows up above it). I've included the 'full code' in my edited question, but **curError** is still apparently 'undefined'.

Comment: Can you share the HTML as it is after all of the data binding has taken place?

Comment: you mean my full HTML for the page? I've added it to the question?

Comment: Sorry - I mean what does it look like after the attributes like `data-bind` etc have run and the elements have been changed (you might need to use the developer tools in your browser to see this). This will help me to understand where the text is you are trying to obtain, because in the example HTML there are no contents in any of the elements you are interacting with.

Comment: since i'm using devExtreme, I can't actually view 'the markup' - but at present, this is only a test project (no binding). I'll hopefully post an image of what it will look like on one of the mobile platforms (IOS/win/android) - devextreme does them all at once

Comment: It seems that the text is placed inside the **dxButton: { text:** *myTextHere* **}, dxaction:...**